# Is there any way to make the body readjust its size when my extension is deployed in all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension with which I try to readjust the main body of the whole page whenever my extension is displayed. It works almost always, but in some pages it does not move the header, for example on Netflix, stackoverflow or superuser.com

My partial solution was to add the body after the frame of my extension:

```
    const html = document.querySelector('html');
    const body = document.querySelector('body');
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    ...Some code ....
    html.insertBefore(iframe, body);
```

Comment: There's no universal solution, you'll have to adjust CSS/DOM for some sites individually.